# Error al ejecutar el comando 'tns preview'

Tags: angular, nativescript

No entiendo este problema:

```
Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-drop-down/angular", relative to: app/tns_modules/
```

Esto se genera cuando ejecuto el comando 'tns preview' en una plataforma Android.

Soy nuevo en NativeScript y estoy estudiandolo a fondo. Realmente necesito ayuda.

Aqui vereis mi `package.json`

```
{
  "description": "sistema de picking Rahmati",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.adealoxica.picking",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.2.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.9",
    "nativescript-angular": "^7.2.3",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^5.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-types": "^6.26.0",
    "babylon": "6.4.5",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.9.1-next-2019-03-12-162713-03",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "name": "picking",
  "author": "Adealoxica"
}
```

Aqui teneis el `name.component.ts` en donde importo el plugin `nativescript-drop-down`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { User } from "../../Model/User/user";
import {UserService} from "../../Model/User/user.service"
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import aplicacion = require("tns-core-modules/application");
import aplicacionSet=require("tns-core-modules/application-settings");
import { ModalDialogParams } from "nativescript-angular/modal-dialog";
import { SelectedIndexChangedEventData } from "nativescript-drop-down";

@Component({
    selector: "login",
    providers: [UserService],
    templateUrl: "./modal/login/login.html",
    styleUrls: ["./modal/login/login-common.css"]
})

export class ViewLogin implements OnInit {
    user: User;
    estadoLog="";
    clave="";

    loading=false;
    public selectedIndex=0;
    public dependientes: Array<string>=[];


    constructor(
        private params:ModalDialogParams,
        private userService:UserService, 
        private page:Page)
    {
        console.log("entrando en login");
        this.user=new User(null);
        this.user.usuario="";
        this.user.clave="";
        this.userService.listar().subscribe(
        (res:Array<User>)=>{
             res.forEach(element => {
                 this.dependientes.push(element.usuario);    
             });
             this.selectedIndex=0;
             console.log("ADENTRO DE LA FUNCION SUBSCRIBE ----- " + res.length); 
            }, 
             (error)=>{
             console.log("Error al hacer LOGIN: " + error);
         });

         this.page.on("unloaded", () => {
             this.params.closeCallback(null);
             });
             console.log("DESPUES DEL page.on");
    }

    public onchange(args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) {
        console.log('El usuario selecionado es ' + this.dependientes[args.newIndex] + " new-> " + args.newIndex + " select-> " + this.selectedIndex);
        this.user.usuario=this.dependientes[args.newIndex];
    }

    teclado(numero:string)
    {
        if(numero=='back')
            this.user.clave=this.user.clave.substring(0,this.user.clave.length-1);
        else
            this.user.clave+=numero;
        this.clave= Array(this.user.clave.length+1).join("*") ;
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {

        this.page.actionBarHidden=true;
        if(aplicacionSet.hasKey("usuario"))
            this.user.usuario=aplicacionSet.getString("usuario");

    }

    summit(){ 
        if(this.loading)
            return;
        this.loading=true;
        this.estadoLog="";
        var res=aplicacion.getResources();
        this.userService.login(this.dependientes[this.selectedIndex],this.user.clave).subscribe(
            (resultado:User)=>
                    {
                        if(resultado==null)
                            {
                                console.log("Login incorrecto: " + resultado);
                                this.estadoLog="Login incorrecto"
                                res["login"]=null;
                                aplicacion.setResources(res);
                                this.loading=false;
                                return false;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                this.estadoLog="Login correcto";   
                                res["login"]=resultado;

                                aplicacion.setResources(res);
                                aplicacionSet.setString("usuario",this.user.usuario);
                                console.log("lo hemos logrado: " + resultado.nombre);
                                console.log("login correcto");
                                this.params.closeCallback(resultado);
                                this.loading=false;
                                return true;
                            }
                    },
            (error)=>
                    {
                        console.log("No ha hecho login: " + error);
                        this.estadoLog = "Login incorrecto";
                        res["login"]=null;
                        aplicacion.setResources(res);
                        this.loading=false;
                        return false;
                    }
        );

    }

    volver()
    {
        this.params.closeCallback(null);
    }

}
```

Lo que mas me llama la atención, es que me genera y compila correctamente todo cuando hago un `tns prepare android` y también `tns run android`

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: LO MAS RECOMENDABLE ES QUE EJECUTES NO CON EL PREVIEW, MAS BIEN SERIA CONECTANDOLO VIA INTERNET ....TE DEJO ALGO ESPERO TE SIRVA ....
conectas el cel modo desarrollador. adb tcpip 5555
adb connect iptuCel:5555
tns run android --device iptuCel:5555 ESO DEBERIA SOLUCIONAR TU ERROR
suerte.

Answer (score -1):

* La respuesta está traducida del inglés a través de google translate.

`tns preview` utiliza un conjunto predefinido de complementos y`nativescript-drop-down` no es uno de ellos (también debería tener una advertencia en la salida de la consola cuando ejecute el comando). Eche un vistazo a la sección [de limitaciones del comando](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/testing/preview#command-limitations).

En otras palabras, no puede usar `preview` con complementos personalizados y debe usar`tns run` si necesita este menú desplegable.

PD Aquí está la lista de los complementos de vista previa soportados a continuación:

"@ angular / animaciones"
    "@ angular / común"
    "@ angular / compilador"
    "@ angular / core"
    "@ angular / formas"
    "@ angular / http"
    "@ angular / platform-browser"
    "@ angular / platform-browser-dynamic"
    "@ angular / router"
    "@ progress-nativechat / nativescript-nativechat":
    "kinvey-nativescript-sdk"
    "nativoscript-acelerómetro"
    "nativescript-angular"
    "nativescript-background-http"
    "nativescript-camera"
    "nativoscript-fresco"
    "nativoscript-geolocalización"
    "nativescript-imagepicker"
    "nativescript-intl"
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager"
    "nativescript-social-share"
    "nativescript-theme-core"
    "nativescript-ui-autocompletar"
    "nativescript-ui-calendar"
    "nativescript-ui-chart"
    "nativescript-ui-dataform"
    "nativescript-ui-gauge"
    "nativescript-ui-listview"
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer"
    "nativescript-vue"
    "reflejar metadatos"
    "rxjs"
    "rxjs-compat"
    "tns-core-modules"
    "zone.js"

Comment: @philip-yepes-gallego Por lo que veo el complemento desplegable no tiene ningún código nativo. En general, dichos complementos podrían usarse en la vista previa cuando pasa el indicador `--bundle` a la CLI de NativeScript. En otras palabras, puedes probar `tns preview --bundle`

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, como podría integrar a mi código el complemente despegable ?. Realmente no se porque no esta integrado... según mi "package.json" esta añadido y si hago un "tns plugin" también aparece.

Comment: No está integrado porque `tns preview` no usa nada de `node_modules`. Para utilizar los complementos, necesita `tns preview --bundle` o` tns run ios / android`.